# Is there a different way I can refactor nested loops?

Tags: php, loops, refactoring

So I have this nested while loop and I am trying to refactor it and make it more readable and also, I am a bit worried about the server timeout (I haven't had any yet, but still), I don't want my server to hang there for a while (even though this hasn't happened yet). Maybe I'm wrong and everything is ok here, but just wanted to make sure I don't make a mistake I'll regret in future..

```
while (count($columns)) {
    $columns = array_values($columns);
    $counter = 0;
    $row = new Row;
    $columnsCount = count($columns);

    while ($counter < $columnsCount) {
        $column = $columns[$counter];
        if ($row->hasSpaceFor($column)) {
            $row->add($column);
            unset($columns[$counter]);
        }
        $counter++;
    }

    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

I played around with it and got this far:

```
while (count($columns)) {
    $columns = array_values($columns);
    $counter = 0;
    $row = new Row;
    $columnsCount = count($columns);

    $this->addColumns($columns, $counter, $columnsCount, $row);

    $rows[] = $row;
}

protected function addColumns(&$columns, $counter, $columnsCount, &$row)
{
    while ($counter < $columnsCount) {
        $column = $columns[$counter];
        if ($row->hasSpaceFor($column)) {
            $row->add($column);
            unset($columns[$counter]);
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably just about it unless you wanted to also break out the stuff happening in the first loop to a function. Also, this is likely off topic here. There is: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I've never used that before.. :)

Comment: Code Review is only appropriate for working code. If the author is sure it works to the best of his knowledge, feel free to post it there and remove it here.

Comment: @Mast, I assume the code works simply because they are asking on advice for refactoring the code for readability.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn The joy of assumptions.

Comment: Yes, this little piece works but not the whole app..

Comment: I don't know what the additional functions in there do, but if it is as simple as it seems, I wouldn't worry about timeouts. You would likely need over several million "cells" (row/column intersections) before you would timeout. If you think this is a problem still, it isn't hard to profile this bit of code with microtime to find out how long it takes to perform these actions. You could also use an actual profiler like xdebug and get times/memory usage.

Comment: that's what I wanted to hear, thanks!